# Conditionally Fill Missing Values According to Subset of Character String

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a data frame that contains missing values. These missing values span multiple variables but arise in said variables, all at once, on specific observations. For example, my data frame looks something like:

```
r1 = c('', 'abc def', '')
r2 = c('1', 'ghi jkl', '2')
r3 = c('', 'mno pqr', '')
df = as.data.frame(rbind(r1, r2, r3))
```

I would like to fill both missing values with "x" in all cases where df$V2 contains 'def', fill both missing values with "y" in all cases where df$V2 contains 'pqr', and leave alone all rows for which df$V2 contains 'jkl'. In other words, I'd like to end up with a data frame that looks like:

```
    V1  V2      V3
r1  x   abc def     x
r2  1   ghi jkl     2
r3  y   mno pqr     y
```

Can I write a function to conditionally fill empty cells in multiple columns of a single row based on a subset of the text of a character variable in that row? Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function that takes as input the data frame, the columns to change the values, and the column to match with. I also included two more optional arguments to capture the pattern (in your case `def` for x and `pqr` for y).Note that I left out the third pattern which leaves the values as are, by assuming that everything else will remain as are. You can modify the function to accept more patterns If you want.

**Function**

```
f1 <- function(df, cols, match_with, to_x = 'def', to_y = 'pqr'){
  df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(i) 
    ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), 'x', 
           ifelse(grepl(to_y, match_with, fixed = TRUE), 'y', i)))
  return(df)
}
```

**Apply**

```
#make sure your columns are characters and NOT factors
df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)

#apply the function
f1(df, cols = c('V1', 'V3'), match_with = df$V2)
#   V1      V2 V3
#r1  x abc def  x
#r2  1 ghi jkl  2
#r3  y mno pqr  y
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure `dplyr` solution, using `case_when` & [the new `.data.` pronoun](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2243):

```
library(dplyr)
r1 = c('', 'abc def', '')
r2 = c('1', 'ghi jkl', '2')
r3 = c('', 'mno pqr', '')
df = as.data.frame(rbind(r1, r2, r3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(
    c("V1", "V3"), 
    funs(case_when(
      grepl("def", .data$V2) ~ "x",
      grepl("pqr", .data$V2) ~ "y",
      TRUE ~ .
    ))
  )
```

Note that you will need the development version of `dplyr` off GH to be able to do this.